# jqGrid not populating

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm am new to jqGrid. I am trying to implement a jqGrid that is populated with data returned by a REST call and several checkboxes that a user can edit to upload a new object to the DB using another rest call. I am having trouble populating the grid.

The issue I am experiencing is that the grid seems to take up the vertical space on the page, but is not displaying any information. The headers of the grid displayed fine when I just had a grid with no data.

During debug with Chrome, I found that the properties I expected to be returned from the row object when evaluated in the console are not there, ie. they are undefined.

Here is the code I am using:

```
var RGrid = [];

$.ajax({
    url: restApi + EndPoint + '/' + Number,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (response) {
        Object2 = response;

        var rData = $('#ResGrid').jqGrid().getRowData();

        for (var i = 0; i < Object2.Requests.length; i++) {
            var existingRows = rData.filter(function (a) {
                return a.rId == Object2.Requests[i].Resource.Id;
            });
            if (existingRows.length == 0) {
                var newObj = {
                    a: Object2.Requests[i].Resource.Name,
                    e: Object2.Requests[i].Resource.Id,
                    f: Object2.Requests[i].Id,
                    d: false,
                    b: false,
                    c: false
                };
                RGrid.push(newObj);
                $('#ResGrid').jqGrid('addRowData', 1, newObj);
            }
        }
    },
    error: function (textStatus) {
        Error('We were unable to retrieve the item');
    }
});

$('#ResGrid').jqGrid({
    defaults: {
        emptyrecords: "No items assigned",
        loadtext: "Loading..."
    },
    data: RGrid,
    autowidth: true,
    datatype: "local",
    colModel: [
        { label: 'a', name: 'a', align: 'left', editable: false },
        {
            label: 'b', name: 'b', align: 'center', editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox',
            editoptions: { value: "True:False" },
            formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false }
        },
        {
            label: 'c', name: 'c', align: 'center', editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox',
            editoptions: { value: "True:False" },
            formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false }
        },
        {
            label: 'd', name: 'd', align: 'center', editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox',
            editoptions: { value: "True:False" },
            formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false }
        },
        { name: 'e', hidden: true },
        { name: 'f', hidden: true }
    ],
    rowNum: 1000,
    height: 'auto',
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: "Desc",
    grouping: false,
    loadonce: true
});
```

I have tried not passing values for the checkbox columns and several overloads of the addRowData method, none have had an effect. Curiously, the objects passed to the RGrid array appear to have all the property-value pairs I expect, so I suspect the issue is either with the colModel declaration or the way I am using addRowData method.

EDIT: The json I receive from the server:

{"Id":4,"JobNumber":"PrNum75","OrderNumber":null,"QuoteNumber":"1401291641","QuoteId":33,"Requests":[{"Id":10,"PlannedDays":[{"Id":20,"Hours":4.0,"Date":"2014-02-20T00:00:00"}],"PlannedSkillDef":{"Id":1,"Description":"IPE Inspector","DefaultRate":200.0},"QuoteSection":{"Id":54,"Description":"Ves","NumberOf":5,"TotalServices":1000.0,"TotalConsumables":100.0,"TotalTravel":5.0,"TotalAmountPerVessel":1105.0,"TravelExpenses":[{"Id":26,"AgreedRate":3.0,"Quantity":1,"TravelDef":{"Id":1,"Description":"Resource & NDT Travel ","UnitDescription":"Km","DefaultRatePerUnit":3.0}},{"Id":27,"AgreedRate":2.0,"Quantity":1,"TravelDef":{"Id":2,"Description":"Mechanical Service Travel","UnitDescription":"Km","DefaultRatePerUnit":2.0}}],"Consumables":[{"Id":16,"Quantity":1,"AgreedPrice":100.0,"ConsumableDef":{"Id":3,"Description":"Cans of MT / PT consumables","UnitPrice":100.0}}],"Services":[{"Id":17,"ServiceDef":{"Id":1,"Description":"Non Destructive Testing - Inspections","DefaultSkill":{"Id":2,"Description":"CPV","DefaultRate":250.0},"TasksRequired":[{"Id":1,"Description":"Thickness Testing"},{"Id":2,"Description":"Surface Crack Testing"},{"Id":3,"Description":"Reporting"},{"Id":4,"Description":"NDT Travel"}],"TravelDefs":[{"Id":1,"Description":"Resource & NDT Travel ","UnitDescription":"Km","DefaultRatePerUnit":3.0},{"Id":2,"Description":"Mechanical Service Travel","UnitDescription":"Km","DefaultRatePerUnit":2.0}],"ConsumableDefs":[{"Id":3,"Description":"Cans of MT / PT consumables","UnitPrice":100.0}]},"DefaultSkill":{"Id":70,"Rate":0.0,"SkillDef":{"Id":2,"Description":"CPV","DefaultRate":250.0}},"AgreedSkill":{"Id":69,"Rate":250.0,"SkillDef":{"Id":1,"Description":"IPE Inspector","DefaultRate":200.0}},"ServiceTasks":[{"Id":92,"TaskHours":1,"NumberOfShifts":1,"NumberOfStaff":1,"ServiceTaskDef":{"Id":1,"Description":"Thickness Testing"}},{"Id":93,"TaskHours":1,"NumberOfShifts":1,"NumberOfStaff":1,"ServiceTaskDef":{"Id":2,"Description":"Surface Crack Testing"}},{"Id":94,"TaskHours":1,"NumberOfShifts":1,"NumberOfStaff":1,"ServiceTaskDef":{"Id":3,"Description":"Reporting"}},{"Id":95,"TaskHours":1,"NumberOfShifts":1,"NumberOfStaff":1,"ServiceTaskDef":{"Id":4,"Description":"NDT Travel"}}]}]},"Resource":{"Id":1,"ADUserName":"###","Name":"Matthew Smith","SkillDefs":[]},"ServiceDef":{"Id":1,"Description":"Non Destructive Testing - Inspections","DefaultSkill":{"Id":2,"Description":"CPV","DefaultRate":250.0},"TasksRequired":[{"Id":1,"Description":"Thickness Testing"},{"Id":2,"Description":"Surface Crack Testing"},{"Id":3,"Description":"Reporting"},{"Id":4,"Description":"NDT Travel"}],"TravelDefs":[{"Id":1,"Description":"Resource & NDT Travel ","UnitDescription":"Km","DefaultRatePerUnit":3.0},{"Id":2,"Description":"Mechanical Service Travel","UnitDescription":"Km","DefaultRatePerUnit":2.0}],"ConsumableDefs":[{"Id":3,"Description":"Cans of MT / PT consumables","UnitPrice":100.0}]}}],"Consumables":[],"TravelAllocations":[]}

The part of interest to me is WorkRequests, where I need the Name and the Id of the Resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out what the issue was. The code declaring and populating the jqGrid was in a script file, which in the page was referenced above the declaration of the table that was supposed to act as the grid. A basic novice mistake on my part.

Thank you all for trying to help me out, and sorry to take up your time. Guess it's back to C# for me...

Answer (score 0):

you can try doing this in `complete: function(){// here your jqgrid}`:

**"loadonce: true"** no need to use this as your datatype is local

```
var RGrid = [];

$.ajax({
    url: restApi + EndPoint + '/' + Number,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (response) {
        Object2 = response;

        var rData = $('#ResGrid').jqGrid().getRowData();

        for (var i = 0; i < Object2.Requests.length; i++) {
            var existingRows = rData.filter(function (a) {
                return a.rId == Object2.Requests[i].Resource.Id;
            });
            if (existingRows.length == 0) {
                var newObj = {
                    a: jobObject2.Requests[i].Resource.Name,
                    b: jobObject2.Requests[i].Resource.Id,
                    c: jobObject2.Requests[i].Id,
                    d: false,
                    e: false,
                    f: false
                };
                RGrid.push(newObj);
            }
        }
    },
    error: function (textStatus) {
        Error('We were unable to retrieve the item');
    },
    complete: function(){

              $('#ResGrid').jqGrid({
                    defaults: {
                        emptyrecords: "No items assigned",
                        loadtext: "Loading..."
                    },
                    data: RGrid,
                    autowidth: true,
                    .........

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you would use `datatype: "json"`. In the case **jqGrid will make the request to the server**. You need just use `url` option like `url: restApi + EndPoint + '/' + Number` and `jsonReader` like `jsonReader: {root: "Requests", repeatitems: false}`. It will inform jqGrid where to find the data in the response. Additionally you would need to use `jsonmap` option to bind columns with the names `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, ... to properties `Resource.Name` and other in the server response.

The mapping of `jobObject2.Requests[i].Resource.Id` and `jobObject2.Requests[i].Id` to `'b'` and `'c'` columns having `formatter: "checkbox"` seems me very suspected. It's strange to have ids which possible value could be `True` or `False` only. Additional problem is the usage of variable `Object2` in the loop, but usage of undefined `jobObject2` in the body of the loop. I suppose that minimal fixing of your current code would be: moving of creating of the grid inside of `success` or `complete` callback and replacing `jobObject2` to `Object2`. I would see the problem as the next one. Your current question is: how to fill the grid with the data returned from the server.

The code which I suggest should look about the following:

```
$('#ResGrid').jqGrid({
    datatype: "json",
    url: restApi + EndPoint + '/' + Number,
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true,
    loadonce: true,
    jsonReader: {
        root: "Requests",
        repeatitems: false
    },
    colModel: [
        { name: "a", jsonmap: "Resource.Name" },
        { name: "b", jsonmap: "Resource.Id", align: "center" },
        { name: "c", jsonmap: "Id", align: "center" }
    ]
    ...
});
```

**UPDATED**: [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user2458781.htm) shows that posted above options work with the last version of JSON data which you posted.

Comment: I made some errors while editing my code for posting, the posted code should be correct now. The false values are for the checkbox columns, which I cannot bind to a property in the json. I tried this option, and get the same result.

Comment: @user2458781: Sorry, but I don't understand your current state. It would be easier if you append the text of your question with test JSON data returned from the server (3-5 rows will be enough). You can catch the exact data returned from the server using Developer Tools of Google Chrome (see "Network" part)

Comment: I have added the json example to the original question.

Comment: @user2458781: JSON data which you posted have the structure which is absolutely other as the code which you posted. For example there are `"WorkRequests"` instead of `"Requests"` in the root. `"WorkRequests"` is array with only **one** item. There are only one item under `"WorkRequests"`. There are no `"Name"` under `WorkRequests[0].Resource` and so on... Which part of the JSON response you want to display in the grid?

Comment: As I explained before, I edited the names in my code before I posted it. I have now edited the json to align with the names, but I did already explain exactly what part of the json I'm trying to consume.

Comment: @user2458781: [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user2458781.htm) shows that the options which I posted posted before work with the last version of JSON data which you posted.

Comment: Is your page using XHTML 1.0 or the HTML 5 standard? Mine is using XHTML

Comment: @user2458781: You need just to open the source of my demo to see DTD of the first line of the page. I use XHTML 1.0 Strict. In the same way other HTML standard will work too.